# set null to false on json request

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Is it possible to configure spring and jackson, to set Boolean field in entity to false, in case, when request does not contain value?

Request

```
{
    title: "aaa"
}
```

Entity:

```
class Entity{
    private String title;//will be 'aaa'
    private Boolean active;//will be 'null'
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: would just declaring it with a default value do the trick?`private Boolean active = false;`

Comment: Any reason you're using a `Boolean` field instead of `boolean` if you don't want to allow it to be null?

Comment: Both ideas good for me